# Doubly Linked List Search Method

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

Working on a search method for my doubly linked list. I'm getting exceptions but I can't seem to figure out how to traverse the list without getting them..

```
    public void searchEntryNode() {
    System.out.println("I'll search through each entry to pull up what you're looking for ");
    System.out.println("Type in what you want ");
    String searchEntry = keyboard.next();

    EntryNode n = head;
    while (head != null) {
        if (head.getFirstName().contains(searchEntry) || head.getLastName().contains(searchEntry) || head.getPhoneNum().contains(searchEntry) || head.getEmail().contains(searchEntry)) { 
            System.out.println("Found a matching entry");
            System.out.println(n.getFirstName() + " " + n.getLastName() + " " + n.getEmail() + " " + n.getPhoneNum());
        }

        if (head.getNext() != null) {
            head = head.getNext();
        }   
        else {
                System.out.println("That's all we found ");
                System.out.println();
                menu();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: I get a null pointer exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at AddressList.searchEntryNode(AddressList.java:87)
 at AddressList.menu(AddressList.java:160)
 at AddressList.addEntryNode(AddressList.java:48)
 at AddressList.menu(AddressList.java:156)
 at AddressList.addEntryNode(AddressList.java:48)
 at AddressList.menu(AddressList.java:156)
 at AddressList.addEntryNode(AddressList.java:48)
 at AddressList.menu(AddressList.java:156)
 at AddressDriver.createList(AddressDriver.java:14)
 at AddressDriver.main(AddressDriver.java:9)

Comment: There's potentially `NullReferenceExceptions` if one of the `get` methods returns no value.

Comment: So which line is 87? Going to assume that one of your entries has no (last name / first name / email / phone number).

Comment: (1) Show us the exact exception you get. (2) Your function never returns; when it reaches the end of the list it calls `menu()` -- and when that returns it'll go around the loop again. (3) Is it possible that one or more of {first name, last name, phone number, email address} might be null even though `head` itself isn't?

Comment: Between when I started writing that and when I finished, I see you already answered question 1 and Graphain said the same as me on point 3. So it goes :-). I agree with Graphain's diagnosis

Comment: Meh, Just realized I'm creating a new list with an empty node.

Comment: @Gareth - I reckon you're right except on point (2). To call `menu()` `head` has to be null, which is the exit condition for the `while` loop. // Edit, I'm wrong, you're right. This will never exit, as `head` is not ever assigned to be a null value. Jackie - you need to remove the `if (head.getNext() != null)` check for assigning the `head` at the end of your function, otherwise `head` will never get to be `null` and you will be stuck in your function forever as Gareth noted.

Comment: Also, don't call the menu from the search method, instead simply return from your method to the menu.

Comment: How do you return from your method to the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your line counts, so I'm guessing blindly here, but I'm going to guess that this line is your problem:

```
if (head.getFirstName().contains(searchEntry) || head.getLastName().contains(searchEntry) || head.getPhoneNum().contains(searchEntry) || head.getEmail().contains(searchEntry))
```

It's probable that one of your entries returns `null` for either `getFirstName`, `getLastName`, `getPhoneNum`, or `getEmail`.

You will have to check each is not `null` before dereferencing (you can't do `null.someMethod()`)

One way of doing this:

```
string firstName = head.getFirstName();
string lastName = head.getLastName();
string phoneNum = head.getPhoneNum();
string email = head.getEmail();

if ((firstName != null && firstName.contains(searchEntry)) 
     || (lastName != null && lastName.contains(searchEntry)) 
     || (phoneNum != null && phoneNum.contains(searchEntry)) 
     || (email != null && email.contains(searchEntry)))
```

Comment: Got it, checking to make sure something isn't null first works. Thanks!